# ContextMenu Tap/Click Event in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, bing-maps, pushpin

If I tap on a pushpin, Contextmenu is opening and displaying the details..
Now I want To Tap/Click on the Contextmenu to do some events..
How to achieve this???
Thanks

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="toolkit:MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:MenuItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Margin="24,0" 
                                   FontSize="26" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}"                                        
                                   Margin="24,0" 
                                   FontSize="22" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"                                        
                                   Margin="24,0" 
                                   FontSize="22" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

        private void Pushpin_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _ppmodel = sender as Pushpin;
        ContextMenu contextMenu =
            ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(_ppmodel);
        contextMenu.DataContext = _viewModel.Pushpins.Where
            (c => (c.Coordinates
                == _ppmodel.Location)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
        {
            contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle taps/clicks on a ContextMenuItem you'll have to add the appropriate event.

e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="toolkit:MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:MenuItem">
                <StackPanel Tap="OnMenuItemTapped">
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter
</Style>
```

Comment: There is no tap event for StackPanel..correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Deepak I can definitely see it in WP7.1 & WP8.0

Comment: I am using WP7 and its not there

Comment: @Deepak I created a WP7.1 app in VS2012 to check when you asked and I saw it there. If it's not there in earlier versions just wrap the StackPanel in something which does support Tap and use that instead.